# I need some explanation on Bigcommerce third-party app authentication

Tags: php, bigcommerce

To authenticate a shop, my configuration looks like this:

```
Bigcommerce_Api::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://storeurl.mybigcommerce.com',
    'username' => 'apiusername',
    'api_key' => 'token'
));
```

These are my questions:

- **store_url**: Is it the store_url of the shop that I am trying to authenticate or the shop url of the account that is attached to the application for testing purposes?
- The same question goes for the **username** and **api_key** .

Thanks

Anyone please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using basic authentication...
store_url is the URL of the store you are connecting to. Same goes for the username and api key.

For a single click app...
you need to use the OAuth2 protocol. You can get the store hash via the Callback URL. Authentication is granted an access token.

I recommend reading up on the [Callback URL](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/callback)

Comment: That is what I thought but do I get that store_url? Could not find it anywhere in their documentation.Sorry for the late reply

Comment: Is this for an app that will be in the Bigcommerce marketplace? Or it going to remain external?

Comment: It is a third party app but will be in the Bigcommerce marketplace. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you will want to look at the callback feature which uses the OAuth protocol. Take a look at the callback feature. I will edit my response accordingly. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/callback

Comment: @developerscott I am only getting scope and code via callback no store hash. Do I need anything extra to get this?

Comment: @developerscott. Samething here, just the scope and the code but no store hash. Is there a link to a quick tutorial which explains better everything I need to know about how to connect a Bigcommerce shop to an external app like the one I am developing? Thanks

Comment: @Rinku - if still having issues please create another question w/your code for that.

Comment: @Lomse - same thing. There are no tutorials. There is just the documentation at developer.bigcommerce.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm maybe a bit late to the party but what I did was via my callback, I grab the store hash value (context) from `request.querystring["context"]`.

I just setup a quick asp.net page using c# which maybe is not what you're looking for if you're working in PHP. Also remember SSL is mandatory. Hope this is of some use.